# Javafx 3D blending

Tags: javafx-8, blending, particle-system

When I try to blend Rectangles in javafx it works only in 2D but not in 3D. Is it possible to blend(BlendMode.ADD) Rectangles or Box-es(with small depth) to construct particle system 3D version in javafx8?

here is the code(using meshes but similar with Rectangles also doesn't work in 3D ) :

```
public class PS2 extends Application {


private PerspectiveCamera ps ;

public MeshView textMesh(){
    float [] points={
        -100f,-100f,0f,
        100f,-100f,0f,
        100f,100f,0f,
        -100f,100f,0f
    } ;

    float [] textCord={
        0f,0f,
        1f,0f,
        1f,1f,
        0f,1f
    } ;

    int[] faces={
        0,0,3,3,1,1,
        0,0,1,1,3,3,
        3,3,2,2,1,1,
        3,3,1,1,2,2

    } ;

    TriangleMesh mesh=new TriangleMesh() ;
    mesh.getPoints().addAll(points);
    mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(textCord);
    mesh.getFaces().addAll(faces);

    MeshView kv=new MeshView() ;
    kv.setMesh(mesh) ;

    PhongMaterial pm=new PhongMaterial() ;
    pm.setDiffuseMap(new Image("file:/c:/pdfs/prs.png"));
    kv.setMaterial(pm);

    return kv ;


}

public void particleSystem(Group g){
    //ArrayList<MeshView> particles=new ArrayList<>() ;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        MeshView mv=textMesh() ;
        double x= (new Random()).nextDouble()*100.0 ;
        double y= (new Random()).nextDouble()*100.0 ;
        double z= (new Random()).nextDouble()*100.0 ;
        mv.setTranslateX(x);
        mv.setTranslateY(y);
        mv.setTranslateZ(z);
        //particles.add(mv) ;
        mv.setBlendMode(BlendMode.ADD);
        g.getChildren().add(mv) ;


    }

}

public void initCamera(Scene scene){
    ps=new PerspectiveCamera(true) ;
    ps.setNearClip(0.1);
    ps.setFarClip(10000);
    ps.setTranslateZ(-2100);
    ps.setTranslateX(100);
    ps.setTranslateY(100);
    scene.setCamera(ps);
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Particle Systems");
    Group root=new Group() ;

    Scene s=new Scene(root,400,400,true) ;
    s.setFill(Color.BLACK);

    initCamera(s) ;
    particleSystem(root);      


    primaryStage.setScene(s);
    primaryStage.show() ;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args) ;
}
```

}

Comment: can you provide some code which doesn't work for you?

Comment: i've added the code